# Merge arrays in an array and add values

Tags: php, arrays

I need to take an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [county_code] => 54045
            [count] => 218
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [county_code] => 54045
            [count] => 115
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [county_code] => 54051
            [count] => 79
        )

)
```

And merge all arrays with the same county_code adding the count, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [county_code] => 54045
            [count] => 333
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [county_code] => 54051
            [count] => 79
        )

)
```

There will be multiple instances of multiple county codes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If there is no built-in PHP function for this need, I would go for a loop through the array with the addition of each count to the dedicated keys of a synthesis array. I will write the code as soon as I go back to my laptop.

Comment: Thank you, Eric.

Comment: Done :) You're welcome @cvc.

Answer (score 0):

As promised:

```
<?php
$initial_array = [
    ['country_code' => 54045, 'count' => 218],
    ['country_code' => 54045, 'count' => 115],
    ['country_code' => 54051, 'count' => 79],
];

$synth = [];
foreach ($initial_array as $sa) { # $sa: subarray
  if (!isset($synth[$sa['country_code']])) {
    $synth[$sa['country_code']] = 0;
  }
  $synth[$sa['country_code']] += $sa['count'];
}
print_r($synth); # Synthesis array: keys are country codes, values are cumulative counts.

# If you need the same format for both the initial and synthesis arrays, then continue with this:
$synth2 = [];
foreach ($synth as $k => $v) {
  $synth2[] = ['country_code' => $k, 'count' => $v];
}
print_r($synth2);
?>
```

A fiddle for this code: https://3v4l.org/M8tkb

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
// your example array
$array = [
    [
        "county_code" => 54045,
        "count" => 218
    ],
    [
        "county_code" => 54045,
        "count" => 115
    ],
    [
        "county_code" => 54051,
        "count" => 79
    ]
];

// intrim step to collect the count.
$intrimArray = [];        
foreach( $array as $data ){
    $countyCode = $data["county_code"];
    if (!$intrimArray[$countyCode]) {
        $intrimArray[$countyCode] = $data["count"];
    } else {
        $intrimArray[$countyCode] = $intrimArray[$countyCode] + $data["count"];
    }
}

// build the final desired array using interim array.
$finalArray = [];
foreach($intrimArray as $countyCode => $totalCount) {
    array_push($finalArray, [
        "county_code" => $countyCode,
        "count" => $totalCount
    ]);
}

var_dump($finalArray);
```